# SQL select two same column on same table but with different ORDER

Tags: sql, oracle

Trainee here.
I need to create a list last names from the same table.

say we have a table named "sample", this table only consists of:

[image]

What I want to do here is both last name column will be selected but have different order, the first column would be ascending and the second column would be descending like the photo below

[image]

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: The names have no inherent ordering -- not alphabetic or anything obvious.  SQL tables represent UNORDERED sets, so I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one option: it splits first and last name into two subqueries which use `row_number` analytic function. It is then used to `join` rows.

Lines #1 - 6 represent your sample data. Query you really need begins at line #7.

```
SQL> with test (last_name, first_name) as
  2    (select 'L1one'  , 'F1one'    from dual union all
  3     select 'L2two'  , 'F2two'    from dual union all
  4     select 'L3three', 'F3hthree' from dual union all
  5     select 'L4four' , 'F4four'   from dual
  6    ),
  7  ln as
  8    (select last_name,
  9       row_Number() over (order by last_name) rn
 10     from test
 11    ),
 12  fn as
 13    (select first_name,
 14       row_number() over (order by first_name desc) rn
 15     from test
 16    )
 17  select l.last_name, f.first_name
 18  from ln l join fn f on f.rn = l.rn
 19  order by l.last_name
 20  /

LAST_NA FIRST_NA
------- --------
L1one   F4four
L2two   F3hthree
L3three F2two
L4four  F1one

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: both last names? I thought it was a typo]**

If that's so, self-join is a better option:

```
SQL> with test (last_name, first_name) as
  2    (select 'L1one'  , 'F1one'    from dual union all
  3     select 'L2two'  , 'F2two'    from dual union all
  4     select 'L3three', 'F3hthree' from dual union all
  5     select 'L4four' , 'F4four'   from dual
  6    ),
  7  temp as
  8    (select last_name,
  9       row_number() over (order by last_name asc) rna,
 10       row_number() over (order by last_name desc) rnd
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  select a.last_name, d.last_name
 14  from temp a join temp d on a.rna = d.rnd
 15  order by a.last_name;

LAST_NA LAST_NA
------- -------
L1one   L4four
L2two   L3three
L3three L2two
L4four  L1one

SQL>
```

Comment: Little note, the op asks for lastname in both columns, just sorted in reverse from each other, but the query should be easily adaptable to that.

Comment: A little note for LittleFoot :), @Joachim. Thank you. I thought that it must have been a typo. If it is not (on a second thought, you're most probably right and I was wrong - that would be too many typos), I added another query which does the job.

Comment: One disadvantage of this approach is that it requires the names to be sorted twice - once `asc` and once `desc`. Sadly, Oracle is not smart enough to be able to use an `asc` sort as a `desc` sort at the same time. This extra work can be avoided; I showed one way in the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it. In a single subquery, assign the ordinal number (`rn`) based on ascending order, but also keep track of the total row count. Then follow with a join.

```
with
  test (last_name, first_name) as (
    select 'L1one'  , 'F1one'    from dual union all
    select 'L2two'  , 'F2two'    from dual union all
    select 'L3three', 'F3hthree' from dual union all
    select 'L4four' , 'F4four'   from dual
   )
, prep (last_name, rn, ct) as (
    select last_name, row_number() over (order by last_name), count(*) over ()
    from   test
  )
select a.last_name as last_name_asc, b.last_name as last_name_desc
from   prep a inner join prep b on a.rn + b.rn = a.ct + 1
;


LAST_NAME_ASC  LAST_NAME_DESC
-------------- --------------
L1one          L4four        
L2two          L3three       
L3three        L2two         
L4four         L1one
```

Comment: Nice, really nice. Smart.